# Show records in ComboBox on different lines

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show all my records in a ComboBox but the records are shown on one line. Here is my code. I made 2 classes from which the data are retrieved.

Data Handler Code:

```
public DataSet DataLoader(string _strQuery)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Clear();

    using (conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn = Connection.getconnection();
        oda = new SqlDataAdapter(_strQuery, conn);
        oda.Fill(ds, "Temp");
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        oda.Dispose();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Data Class Code:

```
public System.String Loadbranch()
{
    string BranchName = "";
    string strquery = "select * from Expense";
    DataHandler dh = new DataHandler();
    System.Data.DataSet dsLoadData = new System.Data.DataSet();
    dsLoadData = dh.DataLoader(strquery);

    if (dsLoadData.Tables["Temp"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dsLoadData.Tables["Temp"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            BranchName += dsLoadData.Tables["Temp"].Rows[i]["ExpenseID"].ToString();
        }
    }

    return BranchName;
}
```

Main Form Where Data Show:

```
private void Edit_User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
    this.MaximumSize = this.Size;

    cbsaveuserid.Items.Add(d.Loadbranch());
}
```

Please help me to show all records in the ComboBox but on different lines.

Comment: Is the question for ASP.NET MVC or for .NET WinForms?

Comment: .net windows form.

Comment: Can you modify the tags?

Comment: sure but can you help me. how can I do .

Comment: please help me out how I do to show records in Combo Box

Comment: If you add the `winforms` tag, people familiar with that technology will see your question and help you to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items represents a *collection* of objects.

Modify your `LoadBranch()` method to return a collection of strings (e.g., `List<string>`), as opposed to one concatenated string.

Modify `Edit_User_Load()` to loop through the collection and add each element to the `cvsaveuserid.Items` collection.

I don't have your code, so I can't compile it, but I think this would work:

```
    public List<string> Loadbranches()
    {
        List<string> branchNames = new List<string>();
        string strquery = "select * from Expense";
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler();
        System.Data.DataSet dsLoadData = new System.Data.DataSet();
        dsLoadData = dh.DataLoader(strquery);

        if (dsLoadData.Tables["Temp"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dsLoadData.Tables["Temp"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                branchNames.Add(dsLoadData.Tables["Temp"].Rows[i]["ExpenseID"].ToString());
            }
        }

        return branchNames;
    }

    private void Edit_User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
        this.MaximumSize = this.Size;

        foreach (string branchName in d.Loadbranches())
        {
            cbsaveuserid.Items.Add(branchName);
        }
    }
```